# Does there exist any direct proof that the Cantor set is countably dense homogeneous?

Tags: cantor-set, homogeneous-spaces

A separable space $X$ is said to be countably dense homogeneous (CDH) if for any two countable dense subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ there exists a homeomorphism $f:X\longrightarrow X$ such that $f(A)=B.$

It is well known that the Cantor set is countably dense homogeneous, as it is  a strongly locally homogeneous Polish space. My questions are the following:

Does there exist any direct proof of that the Cantor set is CDH?

Can anyone suggest a textbook discussing CDH spaces in detail?

Comment: [Here's](https://mathoverflow.net/a/258280/8133) a direct proof of a stronger result; it's a bit overkill, but it's not hard to whip up a simpler argument along the same lines for the weaker result.

Comment: It's a standard back and forth argument as for the case of $\Bbb R^n$ being CDH, see Brouwer's original proof of that and try to adapt. There are no text books for such  homogeneity properties, "just" some monographs, or chapters in handbooks. It's a rather obscure area. A lot is unknown. The best you can do is read all the orginal papers, IMO.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you. I will check.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for the quick reply. I have some doubts in that back and forth method. If not resolved, will discuss in the above mentioned thread itself.

Comment: @SurinderPalSinghKainth It would probably be better to ask a specific MSE question about it (unless your question is pretty short) in order to avoid a long comment thread.